# I lost the view when I enter in multitasking mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm following [Apple's tutorial on SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/getting-started-with-scrumdinger) and the app has a behavior that I can't understand.

If I active multitasking, the current view is completely lost and go back to the previous one.

[image: Gif from the iPhone simulator]

As you can see the timer view is completely gone when I active multitasking. This only happens in the third view (the MeetingView) of the view tree.

Does anyone know why this view has this behavior?

[You can download the complete project here.](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/1ea2eec121b90031e354288912a76357/TranscribingSpeechToText.zip)

Code:

ScrumsView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrumsView: View {
    @Binding var scrums: [DailyScrum]
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State private var isPresentingNewScrumView = false
    @State private var newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
    let saveAction: ()->Void
    
    @State var navigated = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($scrums) { $scrum in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(scrum: $scrum)) {
                    CardView(scrum: scrum)
                }
                .listRowBackground(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Daily Scrums")
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: {
                isPresentingNewScrumView = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
            .accessibilityLabel("New Scrum")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingNewScrumView) {
            NavigationView {
                DetailEditView(data: $newScrumData)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                            Button("Dismiss") {
                                isPresentingNewScrumView = false
                                newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
                            }
                        }
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                            Button("Add") {
                                let newScrum = DailyScrum(data: newScrumData)
                                scrums.append(newScrum)
                                isPresentingNewScrumView = false
                                newScrumData = DailyScrum.Data()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
//        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
//            if phase == .inactive { saveAction() }
//        }
    }
}

struct ScrumsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrumsView(scrums: .constant(DailyScrum.sampleData), saveAction: {})
        }
    }
}
```

DetailView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var scrum: DailyScrum
    
    @State private var data = DailyScrum.Data()
    @State private var isPresentingEditView = false
    
    @State private var starButton = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Meeting Info")) {
                NavigationLink(destination: MeetingView(scrum: $scrum)) {
                    Label("Start Meeting", systemImage: "timer")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
                HStack {
                    Label("Length", systemImage: "clock")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes) minutes")
                }
                .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
                HStack {
                    Label("Theme", systemImage: "paintpalette")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(scrum.theme.name)
                        .padding(4)
                        .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)
                        .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
                        .cornerRadius(4)
                }
                .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Attendees")) {
                ForEach(scrum.attendees) { attendee in
                    Label(attendee.name, systemImage: "person")
                }
            }
            Section(header: Text("History")) {
                if scrum.history.isEmpty {
                    Label("No meetings yet", systemImage: "calendar.badge.exclamationmark")
                }
                ForEach(scrum.history) { history in
                    NavigationLink(destination: HistoryView(history: history)) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "calendar")
                            Text(history.date, style: .date)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(scrum.title)
        .toolbar {
            Button("Edit") {
                isPresentingEditView = true
                data = scrum.data
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingEditView) {
            NavigationView {
                DetailEditView(data: $data)
                    .navigationTitle(scrum.title)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                            Button("Cancel") {
                                isPresentingEditView = false
                            }
                        }
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                            Button("Done") {
                                isPresentingEditView = false
                                scrum.update(from: data)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: MeetingView(scrum: $scrum), isActive: $starButton) {
                Button {
                    starButton.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Start Meeting")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)
                .tint(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            DetailView(scrum: .constant(DailyScrum.sampleData[0]))
        }
    }
}
```

MeetingView (It disappears when the app is inactive)

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct MeetingView: View {
    @Binding var scrum: DailyScrum
    @StateObject var scrumTimer = ScrumTimer()
    @StateObject var speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer()
    @State private var isRecording = false
    private var player: AVPlayer { AVPlayer.sharedDingPlayer }

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .fill(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            VStack {
                MeetingHeaderView(secondsElapsed: scrumTimer.secondsElapsed, secondsRemaining: scrumTimer.secondsRemaining, theme: scrum.theme)
                MeetingTimerView(speakers: scrumTimer.speakers, isRecording: isRecording, theme: scrum.theme)
                MeetingFooterView(speakers: scrumTimer.speakers, skipAction: scrumTimer.skipSpeaker)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)
        
        .onAppear {
            scrumTimer.reset(lengthInMinutes: scrum.lengthInMinutes, attendees: scrum.attendees)
            scrumTimer.speakerChangedAction = {
                player.seek(to: .zero)
                player.play()
            }
            speechRecognizer.reset()
            speechRecognizer.transcribe()
            isRecording = true
            scrumTimer.startScrum()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            //            scrumTimer.stopScrum()
            //            speechRecognizer.stopTranscribing()
            //            isRecording = false
            let newHistory = History(attendees: scrum.attendees, lengthInMinutes: scrum.timer.secondsElapsed / 60, transcript: speechRecognizer.transcript)
            scrum.history.insert(newHistory, at: 0)
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct MeetingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MeetingView(scrum: .constant(DailyScrum.sampleData[0]))
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not read all, but what I see is that in meeting view, when it disappear (which may be called when going to background) it add the scrum at the beginning of the list which may force the previous view to redraw and so dismiss the meeting view.

Comment: Even if I delete all the code inside of .onDisappear, the view is still lost. Another thing I have tried, is to go directly from ScrumsView to MeetingView, and so it does seem to work. So, maybe the problem is in DetailView. But I haven't been able to know why yet.